# How is zope 3 view security handled in Plone

Tags: plone, zope

When one registers a view in ZCML like:

```
<browser:page
   for="*"
   name="reporter"
   class=".reporter.report_form_frame"
   permission="cmf.SetOwnPassword"
   />
```

- In which point of traversing stack Zope machinery checks for this permission
- Which component keep track of views and their permissions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `browser:page` handler sets the permission on the view class itself. There is no central component that keeps track.

In Zope 2, that is delegated to the `AccessControl.security.protectClass()` function, which is the equivalent of adding a `ClassSecurityInfo` object to your view class:

```
from AccessControl.SecurityInfo import ClassSecurityInfo

class report_form_name(BrowserView):
    security = ClassSecurityInfo()
    security.declareObjectProtected('cmf.SetOwnPassword')
```

or, if making the view public (`zope.Public`) or private (`zope.Private`), the `security.declareObjectPublic()` or `security.declareObjectPrivate()` calls are used instead.

The class security info is translated into a `__roles__` and `__ac_permissions__` attributes on the class that the publisher inspects when checking permissions. See the [Security chapter](http://docs.zope.org/zope_secrets/security.html) of the Zope Secrets book for details on how those work.